# Variable 'x' is used before being assigned

Tags: typescript

I got the following static method in the `Logger` class. I quite don't understand `tsserver` error.

#### LogLevel

```
const enum LogLevel {
    ERROR = 0,
    WARN = 1
}

export default LogLevel;
```

#### Logger

```
    static defaultHandler(level: LogLevel, ...message: readonly string[]) {
        if (!Logger.isLevelEnabled(level)) return;

        let handler: Function;
        switch (level) {
            case LogLevel.ERROR:
                handler = console.error;
                break;

            case LogLevel.WARN:
                handler = console.warn;
                break;
        }

        // [tsserver 2454] Variable 'handler' is used before being assigned
        handler(...message);
    }
```

Since `LogLevel` is an Enum, the handler will never be unassigned. If I add an `if`, `tslint` complains about that.

```
        // [tslint 1] expression is always true (strict-type-predicates)
        if (handler !== undefined) handler(...message);
```

I even removed `no-let` `tslint` rule because it for some reason doesn't see assignment within the `switch` case and want me to use `const handler: Function;`. Can anyone explain what is going on here.

Comment: Provide a `default` in switch, otherwise it might be undefined, or initialize it with somehting

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
let handler: Function;
switch (level) {
    case LogLevel.ERROR:
        handler = console.error;
        break;

    case LogLevel.WARN:
        handler = console.warn;
        break;
}
```

You are only handling `ERROR` and `WARN`.  The options are more:

```
ERROR = 0,
WARN = 1,
INFO = 2,
DEBUG = 3,
VERBOSE = 4
```

## Fix

Add a default to cater for remaining cases:

```
    let handler: Function;
    switch (level) {
        case LogLevel.ERROR:
            handler = console.error;
            break;

        case LogLevel.WARN:
            handler = console.warn;
            break;

        default: 
            handler = console.log;
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Since they edited the question, it's worth to mention that it doesn't make a difference if there are more options available. The only important thing is that it might be undefined without the default

Comment: extremely sorry. I removed some of the switch cases since It's hard to look at. I'm actually handling all values in `enum`

Comment: Again @CoderS that doesn't matter. You need a default value

Comment: @CoderS The code analyzer does not recognize that you handle all enum values. It reasons "if there is no `default` then `handler` may not get assigned".

Comment: @chrispbacon So `strict-type-predicates` sees the Enum and `tsserver` doesn't right?

Comment: Still, I'm confused why `no-let` doesn't see the assignment though. With or without default case it wants me to change `let  handler` to `const handler`